# getJSON object not appearing in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am a beginner testing getJSON in a simple front-end project. I've learned that I can't use the file:// URL prefix that I've been using previously, and must simulate a server (is this correct?). I've utilized Python's built-in server functionality by typing in **python3 -m http.server 8000** into the terminal (OS X) from my project directory.

I can now type http://0.0.0.0:8000/ into my browser and it will load my index.html. I have two other files: app.js and aceOfSpades.json, which are located in a folder called javascripts, which sits at the same level as index.html.

*When index.html is loaded, the only value displayed in the console is "hello world"*. This tells me that app.js is being correctly loaded, but the getJSON function is either (1) not seeing the aceOfSpades.json file, (2) is seeing the file but not placing its object into the "card" parameter, or (3) is possibly getting caught up in my Python built-in server. Perhaps it's something else entirely.

When I look in the "sources" tab of the Chrome developer panel, the only file listed in the javascripts folder is app.js. aceOfSpades.json is nowhere to be found!

My question: why isn't my JSON object being printed to the console given the following code? How can I solve this? Thank you.

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
var main = function () {
    "use strict";

    $.getJSON("/javascripts/aceOfSpades.json", function (card) {
        console.log("your card should appear after this");
        console.log(card);
    });

    console.log("hello world");
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

**aceOfSpades.json**:

```
{
    rank: "ace",
    suit: "spades"
}
```

Comment: do you at least get *""your card should appear after this""* in the console? that's relatively important information.

Comment: No, the only thing that appears is "hello world"

Comment: then add an error handler. it's likely going to tell you "parseerror". What could parseerror mean?

Comment: I'm familiar with error handling in Python, but not JavaScript. Should I attempt to implement try/catch/throw?

Comment: Since this is a jQuery ajax method that returns a jqXHR, you can use the .fail method. `.fail(function (jqXHR, textstatus, message) {/* log all three */});` http://api.jquery.com

Comment: thanks Kevin, my issue turned to be simple JSON object formatting. I wrote it as a JavaScript object, neglecting the extra quotes I needed... Regardless, I will study this error handling method for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because your properties aren't surrounded by quotes, resulting in invalid JSON.

```
{
    "rank": "ace",
    "suit": "spades"
}
```

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (emphasis added):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. **For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes.** For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: embarrassing! that solved my problem. hopefully this will serve as a reminder to other newbies that details can make-or-break! thank you

Comment: Pro-Tip: Use a JSON Lint/Validation tool to verify JSON is formatted properly whenever you manually create JSON files.

Comment: better  yet, don't build json by hand. And if you do anyway, use an editor that will lint it for you, like atom.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on client side, it can't load local files unless [the browser supports it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

```
$.getJSON("/javascripts/aceOfSpades.json", function (card) {
        console.log("your card should appear after this");
        console.log(card);
});
```

try:

```
$.getJSON("http://0.0.0.0:8000/javascripts/aceOfSpades.json", function (card) {
        console.log("your card should appear after this");
        console.log(card);
});
```

Comment: fortunately he doesn't appear to be trying to load local files. a relative path `/foo/bar` while viewing an html file on a server `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` will point to the server.

Comment: But javascript runs on client, then when the code executes it will try to search on local path (eg. on client's machine)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! it turns out I had simply forgotten quotes in the JSON object. I had written it as a regular JavaScript object. rookie mistake!

Comment: sorry, but, you are mistaken. if you're on `http://foobar.com/index.html`, `<a href="/foobar.html">`  will send you to `http://foobar.com/foobar.html`. the same thing happens with getJSON. the path change happens in the client, in both situations.

Comment: If you load the html file from the local file system (e.g. by double-clicking it in the file Explorer) then Ajax calls to files with relative path URLs will also work to load local files. But that doesn't apply here given the OP is using a web server.

Comment: Indeed, my bad! Sorry!